# Format phone numbers excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in excel 2003 that contacts phone numbers. Thousands of rows of phone numbers. Problem is they are not all formatted the same way, some are (123) 455-3983, some are 332.333.5555, etc. I need them all to be 123-456-7890. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column with the following formula...

```
=TEXT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),")","")," ",""),"-",""),".","")),"000-000-0000")
```

...then Copy + Paste Special -> Values and delete the original column.

**How It Works:**

- The nested `SUBSTITUTE()` functions strip out any spaces, brackets, dots and dashes.
- The `VALUE()` function converts the result from text to a number
- The `TEXT()` function converts it back to text applying the format 000-000-0000. This nicely handles phone numbers beginning with one or more zeroes.

If your input contains any more unwanted formatting, use more nested `SUBSTITUTE()` functions to remove them.